# How to add number like 1+1+1=3 not "1"+"1"+"1" = 111 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var health = prompt("Type in health");
var attack = prompt("Type in attack");
var defense = prompt ("Type in defense");
function calculatestats(health,attack,defense){
    return health/4 + attack + defense
}
alert (calculatestats(health,attack,defense));
```

I want to make it output "3" when I type in 4, 1, and 1. The javascript is adding the characters, "1", "1", and "1". I want to add it Mathematically, and make it output 3, not 111. 
Thank you.

Comment: convert the strings to numbers....

Comment: use parseInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt or parseFloat if you want to include floating point numbers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prompt()` returns a string. You have to do explicit type conversion using `+` or `parseInt`:

```
function calculatestats(health,attack,defense){
  return +health/4 + +attack + +defense;
}
```

Better way:

```
function calculatestats(health,attack,defense){
  return parseInt(health)/4 + parseInt(attack) + parseInt(defense);
}
```

Comment: What does that + in front of "health/4", "attack", "defense" do? Also, what does parseInt do? Thanks.

Comment: @Ardent Both do a type conversion from String to Integer...

Comment: I had to wait for about 5 mins in order to accept the answer :^)

Comment: @Ardent Thanks mate... Appreciated...